# How to extract href attribute in html source code

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is HTML source code that I am dealing with:

```
<a href="/people/charles-adams" class="gridlist__link">
```

So what I want to do is to extract the href attribute, in this case would be "/people/charles-adams", with beautifulsoup module. I need this because I want to get html source code with soup.findAll method for that particular webpage. But I am struggling to extract such attribute from the webpage. Could anyone help me with this problem?

P.S.
I am using this method to get html source code with Python module beautifulSoup:

```
request = requests.get(link, headers=header)
html = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
refs = soup.find_all('a')
for i in refs:
    if i.has_attr('href'):
        print(i['href'])
```

It should output:

```
/people/charles-adams
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `beautifulsoup` to find all anchor tags with `soup.find_all('a')`. Then you can filter it with list comprehension and get the links.

```py
request = requests.get(link, headers=header)
html = request.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('a')
tags = [tag for tag in tags if tag.has_attr('href')]
links = [tag['href'] for tag in tags]
```

`links` will be `['/people/charles-adams']`

Comment: @Vladimir that would work but I think its more clear what is happening when spread out over multiple lines.